# Django Graphos Chart Not Loaded On Table Update Using Ajax

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have been using django graphos and it works fine till i realize that the chart is not drawn when i update my table through ajax instead of a page refresh. Let me describe the issue further.

1. When my page is loaded for the first time, all the charts are loaded properly using {{chart.as_html}} . I am usng django by the way .
2. This charts are displayed in a table.
3. But when user selects different value from a dropdown and click reload, my code will only update the table through ajax instead of a whole page refresh. Unfortunately , when the table is updated, the chart with new data is not displayed. It just appears blank. I can see all the data from the developer tools but the chart just fail to appear.
4. I have checked through various topics but I am unable to get it working.
5. Part of my main html file

   ```
                       {% if objects %}

                       {% for obj in objects %}
                       <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{obj.name}}" data-parent="#myGroup" class="accordion-toggle">
                       <!--tr>-->
                           <td style="border:0;"><img src='{{STATIC_URL}}/static/images/{{obj.name}}.png' class="infostockIcon"></td>

                           {% if obj.risk == "high" %}

                           {% if obj.dpr == "high" %}
                           <td class="tablerisk"><strong> * {{obj.name}} </strong></td>
                           {% else %}
                           <td class="tablerisk"><strong> {{obj.name}} </strong></td>
                           {% endif %}

                           <td class="tablerisk"> {{obj.stock_price}} </td>
                           <td class="tablerisk" style="color: black;"> {{obj.option_strategy}} </td>
                           <td class="tablerisk" style="color: black;"> {{obj.whiz_strategy}} </td>
                           <td class="tablerisk"> {{obj.strike_price}} </td>
                           <td class="tablerisk"> {{obj.expiry_date}} </td>
                           <td class="tablerisk"> {{obj.premium}} </td>
                           <td class="tablerisk"> {{obj.roi}} </td>

                           {% else %}

                           {% if obj.dpr == "high" %}
                           <td><strong> * {{obj.name}} </strong></td>
                           {% else %}
                           <td><strong> {{obj.name}} </strong></td>
                           {% endif %}

                           <td> {{obj.stock_price}} </td>
                           <td> {{obj.option_strategy}} </td>
                           <td> {{obj.whiz_strategy}} </td>
                           <td> {{obj.strike_price}} </td>
                           <td> {{obj.expiry_date}} </td>
                           <td> {{obj.premium}} </td>
                           <td> {{obj.roi}} </td>
                           {% endif %}
                           <td style="border:0;"><span class="caret black"></span></th></td>

                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                           <td style="border: 0;padding: 0 !important;"></td>
                           <td colspan="8" style="padding: 0 !important; border: none;">
                               <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="{{obj.name}}">

                                   <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
                                       <li data-toggle="tab" class="active">
                                           <a href="#{{obj.name}}monthseason" data-toggle="tab">Monthly Seasonality</a>
                                       </li>
                                       <li data-toggle="tab">
                                           <a href="#{{obj.name}}weekseason" data-toggle="tab">Weekly Seasonality</a>
                                       </li>
                                       <li data-toggle="tab">
                                           <a href="#{{obj.name}}dividend" data-toggle="tab">Dividend</a>
                                       </li>
                                       <li data-toggle="tab">
                                           <a href="#{{obj.name}}data" data-toggle="tab">{{obj.name}} Info</a>
                                       </li>
                                   </ul>


                                   <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                                       <div class="tab-pane active" id="{{obj.name}}monthseason">
                                           <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                   <h4>Monthly Seasonality<img src='{{STATIC_URL}}/static/info.png'  class="infoIcon" style="float: none; right: 0px; margin-left: 5px" /></h4>
                                                   <div id="gchart_div">
                                                       {{ obj.monthly_chart.as_html}}
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>  
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="tab-pane" id="{{obj.name}}weekseason">
                                           <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                   <h4>Weekly Seasonality<img src='{{STATIC_URL}}/static/info.png'  class="infoIcon" style="float: none; right: 0px; margin-left: 5px"/></h4>

                                                   {{ obj.weekly_chart.as_html}}

                                               </div>
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="tab-pane" id="{{obj.name}}dividend">
                                           <!--div style="padding-left: 2%;" >-->
                                           <div class="row">

                                                   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 alignLeft">
                                                       <label >TTM Dividend Yield:</label>
                                                       <label >{{obj.ttm_dividend_yield}}</label>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 alignLeft">
                                                       <label >Ex-Dividend Date:</label>
                                                       <label >{{obj.ex_div}}</label>
                                                   </div>
                                           </div>
                                           <!--/div>-->
                                           <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                   <h4>Dividend Yield<img src='{{STATIC_URL}}/static/info.png'  class="infoIcon" style="float: none; right: 0px; margin-left: 5px"/></h4>

                                                   {{obj.div_yearly_chart.as_html}}

                                               </div>
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="tab-pane alignRight" id="{{obj.name}}data">
                                           <div style="padding-left: 2%;" >
                                               <div class="row">
                                                   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 alignLeft">
                                                       <label >Sector:</label>
                                                       <label >{{obj.sector}}</label>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 alignLeft">
                                                       <label >Industry:</label>
                                                       <label >{{obj.industry}}</label>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="row">

                                                   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 alignLeft">
                                                       <label >Earning Date:</label>
                                                       <label >{{obj.earnings_date}}</label>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 alignLeft">
                                                       <label >Ex-Dividend Date:</label>
                                                       <label >{{obj.ex_div}}</label>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>

                                               <div class="row">
                                                   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 alignLeft">
                                                       <label >52 Week Range:</label>
                                                       <label >{{obj.year_range}}</label>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 alignLeft">
                                                       <label >5 Year Low:</label>
                                                       <label >{{obj.five_year_low}}</label>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="row">

                                                   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 alignLeft">
                                                       <label >DPR:</label>
                                                       <label >{{obj.dpr_value}}</label>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 alignLeft">
                                                       <label >Latest News:</label>
                                                       <a href={{obj.url}}>Seeking Alpha</a>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                           </div>
                                           <br>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>

                               </div>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
   ```
6. My ajax call:
     `var $myGroup = $('#myGroup');
     $myGroup.on('show.bs.collapse','.collapse', function() {
     $myGroup.find('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
     });

   ```
           $('#tabs li a').click(function (e) {
               $('#tabs li a.active').removeClass('active');
               $(this).parent('li a').addClass('active');
           });

           $("#loadprofit").on("click", function(e)
           {
           //alert("asdas");
           e.preventDefault();
           var selectedOption = $("#strategy").val();
           var selectedDate = $("#strategy2").val();
           csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
           $.ajax({
               method: "POST",
               url: window.location.href,
               data: { selected_option: selectedOption,selected_date:selectedDate,csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token },
           })
           .done(function( msg )
           {
               console.log(msg);
               $("#sct tbody").html(msg);
           });
       });
   </script>
   {% endblock %}
   ```

   `
7. This whole table gets updated when user clicks on a button. Then it calls views.py and table gets updated with the latest value. But {{ obj.monthly_chart.as_html}} is not loaded and it appears blank although i can see the whole chart drawing function and the data form the developer tool

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: provide an example of your code please

Comment: Maybe related to the chart library you're using with Django Graphos? I suggest mimicking the behavior in front end first using the chart library of your choice, before using Django Graphos. This is to make sure if you can update the chart in real time without refreshing.

Comment: added my code above.